# Find and replace instances of "{any-integer}" using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So as part of a web-app, I'm attempting to find particular sets of characters within my markup and replace them with other elements as necessary (this converts them into icons rather than plain text).

```
$timeout(function () {
                $('.collapsible').collapsible();


                $(".manaCost:contains('{B}')").html(function (_, html) {
                    return html.replace(/{B}/g, "<i class=\"ms ms-b\"></i>");
                });

                $(".manaCost:contains('{R}')").html(function (_, html) {
                    return html.replace(/{R}/g, "<i class=\"ms ms-r\"></i>");
                });

                $(".manaCost:contains('{W}')").html(function (_, html) {
                    return html.replace(/{W}/g, "<i class=\"ms ms-w\"></i>");
                });

                $(".manaCost:contains('{G}')").html(function (_, html) {
                    return html.replace(/{G}/g, "<i class=\"ms ms-g\"></i>");
                });

                $(".manaCost:contains('{U}')").html(function (_, html) {
                    return html.replace(/{U}/g, "<i class=\"ms ms-u\"></i>");
                });

                $(".manaCost:contains('{ANY-INTEGER BETWEEN BRACES}')").html(function (_, html) {
                    return html.replace(/{ANY-INTEGER BETWEEN BRACES}/g, "<i class=\"ms ms-SAME-INTEGER\"></i>");
                });

}, 0);
```

All of the ones with a letter inside of them (for example, '{B}'} work just fine, but the integer one is a little more complicated. I need to find any instances of an integer within brackets, but then also need to apply that same integer to the class within the replacement element. Anyone know how I would go about this?

Comment: Uh, `/\{(\d)\}/g` ?

Comment: Or you need to escape the braces if looking for a specific integer value: `/\{1\}/g`. It may also be worth changing your logic to select the `.manaCost` elements *once*, then perform the replacement on them all. It sounds odd, but DOM accesses are so much slower than a regex that it would likely be much faster than your current pattern

Comment: Read something about Regular expressions, it will help you.

Comment: Yeah I knew it would be using regular expressions, I just wasn't aware that I would be able to capture whatever is found (as I need to use that same integer within the class). Cheers guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like `/\{(\d)\}/g` would capture the integer so you can get it with `$1` etc

```js
$("#test").html(function (_, html) {
 return html.replace(/\{(\d)\}/g, "<i class=\"s$1\">$1</i>");
});
```

```css
.s2 {color: red}
.s3 {color: blue}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
   test {2} {3} something
</div>
```

As Rory mentioned, you should consider doing all the replacing at once, and there's really no need to check if every element contains what you're looking for, just do

```
$(".manaCost").html(function(_, html) {
  return html.replace(/\{B\}/g, "<i class=\"ms ms-b\"></i>")
             .replace(/\{R\}/g, "<i class=\"ms ms-r\"></i>")
             .replace(/\{W\}/g, "<i class=\"ms ms-w\"></i>")
             .... etc
});
```

Comment: Cheers yeah that's done it. Didn't know about accessing the value via $1 etc. so thanks for telling me about it.

Comment: Also yeah I've adjusted it so it does all the replacing at once